# How to call function from router template?

Tags: vue.js

I am doing very simple page with url's switching. In one of url I need to call `@click` methods. Here is my code:

```
const NotFound = { template: '<p>Page not found</p>' }
const Home = { template: '<p>home page</p>' }
const Faq = { template: '<p>Faq page</p>' }
const Book = { template: `
<div>
    <button @click="foo()">test</button>
</div>
    ` }
const routes = [
  {path: '/', component: Home},
  {path: '/book', component: Book},
  {path: '/faq', component: Faq}
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes // short for `routes: routes`
    })

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  data: {

  },
  methods: 
  {
    foo()
    {
        console.log("ffffff");
    }
  }
})
```

But I am getting error: `Property or method "foo" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're trying to define child component(book)'s method in parent component. Please just move methods property from parent component to child component.
Here's a sample.

```js
const NotFound = { template: '<p>Page not found</p>' }
const Home = { template: '<p>home page</p>' }
const Faq = { template: '<p>Faq page</p>' }
const Book = { template: `
<div>
    <button @click="foo()">test</button>
</div>
    `
  , methods: // <-- here you go
  {
    foo()
    {
        console.log("ffffff");
    }
  }}
const routes = [
  {path: '/', component: Home},
  {path: '/book', component: Book},
  {path: '/faq', component: Faq}
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes // short for `routes: routes`
    })

Vue.use(VueRouter);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  data: {

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/2.7.0/vue-router.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <router-link :to="{ path: '/' }">Home</router-link>
  <router-link :to="{ path: '/faq' }">FAQ</router-link>
  <router-link :to="{ path: '/book' }">book</router-link>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```